# How to to automate USSD apps

Tags: ussd

I am currently working on a USSD application that is aimed towards lower end java phones.

Is there a way i can automate the USSD application thru some available tool?

-Siva

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in testing USSD requests, not the UI/logic testing of your app that uses USSD just as a transport, please try SMSlib. It supports USSD request and USSD responce analyze send via 3g modem or mobile phone plugged to PC.

As far as I know, there is no way to write UI tests for j2me apps using some real devices (as I understand, it is critically to use real devices, not emulators to send real ussd/sms requests via this app).